# How do I automerge non-conflicting conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just started working on a fairly big git merge and it's showing ~50 files with conflicts. When I use `git mergetool` or simply go to resolve conflicts in Visual Studio - almost all of these files show 0 conflicts with some "AutoMerged" lines. I'm pretty sure I haven't made any significant changes to the files and if the same lines in both files haven't been changed - I can accept these merges in all such cases. I can't find a way to do it though other than manually clicking through the ~50 files and clicking "Accept Merge". I'd really rather do a batch AutoMerge on all files that it is possible. Is there a way to do it with git, vs or otherwise?

Comment: Git *did* do an automerge.  Are your line endings screwed up?  Did you not check in a `.gitattributes`?  Do different developers have different `core.autocrlf` settings?

Comment: Git is very conservative about merge conflicts.  For instance, if both sides added or deleted empty lines Git sometimes considers that a merge conflict, but a mergetool doesn't, so when you load up the file in the mergetool it doesn't see any conflicts.  I don't know of a way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept changes from the branch you merge in, without resolving conflicts since you are sure the conflicts only occurs because of empty lines/whitespace/etc..., you may consider the merge strategy with "theirs" option :

```
git merge -s theirs branchtomerge
```

Check http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge to ensure this is really what you want.

Comment: That's not really what I want since I might have changes in these files in my own branch, but if the changes are in other parts of the same files or only in line endings - this is something that VS can resolve on a file by file basis.